# Ordinary differential equation using matrices

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving a problem regarding ODE and kinda got stuck on the last two lines. Could someone do this step-by-step? I've tried to multiply matrices and mess around with them but got no clue how to get to such a "clean" outcome.

> [image]

Comment: You need to ask a specific question. What do you mean by 'got stuck'?